# JavaFX program remote-controlled from Android

Tags: java, android, javafx-2, javafx, remote-control

I wrote program in JavaFX. Now I want to write program to Android, which will be used to remotely control my application in JavaFX on notebook by WiFi.

For example, in notebook I have database, and program in JavaFX select some data and create list. In JavaFX program I can do all with this list. And I want have application on Android, where I can view current list from notebook. When I will remove an element of the list on Android, on notebook this element will be removed. When I will add one element on notebook, on Android do the same.

I think about WebServices on notebook, but then whole core must be in server application (common resource). Programs on notebook and Android will be observer and both of them in every second must ask server if anything be changed. I think this solution might have a problem with performance.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use a database server and access the database on your notebook directly from the android app

Comment: And current program state should be saved in database?

Comment: Yes. After editing a value in your program it is persist in the database and can accessed from the app and vice versa.